SystemVerilog issue with assignment pattern in port connection
My SystemVerilog is a little bit rusty, and I'm trying to reacquaint myself with it. I have some RTL that looks like this:
typedef logic node;
typedef struct packed {
  node a;
  node b;
} type1;

module foo(type1 sig);
...
endmodule

Module foo is instantiated like this:
foo u0(.sig('{1'b1, 1'b0}));

Questions:

I understand {1'b1, 1'b0} is concatenation of two bits. But, what is the meaning of the single tick before {}?

This type of RTL compiles ok in Synopsys VCS, but when I try to read it in with Synopsys Fusion Compiler, it is giving me an error indicating:
The construct 'assignment pattern in port connection' is not supported.


The tool does not like the '{} assignment. How should I adjust the RTL to resolve this error?

The single tick is used to initialize the individual struct members. Each comma-separated element inside the braces corresponds to a struct member. Without the single tick, you're just concatenating raw bits without regards to the struct.
The compiler doesn't seem to like that particular syntax. You could try assigning it to a variable and using that in the port. E.g. something like this:
type1 sig;
assign sig = '{1'b1, 1'b0};
foo u0(.sig(sig));



what is the meaning of the single tick before {}?

That syntax is known as an assignment pattern.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2023, section 10.9 Assignment patterns:

Assignment patterns are used for assignments to describe patterns of
assignments to structure fields and array elements.   An assignment
pattern is built from braces, keys, and expressions and is prefixed
with an apostrophe.

I get compile errors with your code on VCS and the Cadence simulator.
Regardless, the easiest thing to try is to create a new variable, then connect the variable to the module instance:
type1 sig = '{1'b1, 1'b0};

foo u0(.sig(sig));

If that doesn't work, don't use a struct port.
